# To the Power Of

Tags: javascript

I was recently looking at some other questions and doing a looking around and came across someone using `x^y` (x to the power of y).

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Here are a few examples and their outputs.

```
2^2 // 0
2^3 // 1
2^4 // 6

Math.pow(2,2) // 4
Math.pow(2,3) // 8
Math.pow(2,4) // 16
```

Why doesn't `num^power` work? I swear it used to. What arithmetic is it actually doing?

Comment: Sorry this is a duplicate. Didn't know what to search for to see if it already existed :3

Answer (score 3):

`^` is a logical, bitwise operator for the `XOR` operation.

XOR is an operation which for any bit at a given position, results 1 (true) if this bit has different values for two compared variables (and 0 otherwise).

Here are your three examples in binary:

```
    10 (2)          10 (2)         010 (2)
XOR 10 (2)      XOR 11 (3)     XOR 100 (4)
   ---             ---            ----
    00 (0)          01 (1)         110 (6)
```